# Error when trying to apply a function to a pandas timeseries resample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, time-series

I'm trying to get the first element of the time series but it seems there's some problems when I try it to get it using apply. For example:

```
a = pd.Series(['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-04', '2014-01-09'])
a = pd.to_datetime(a).reset_index().set_index(0)
a

            index
0   
2014-01-01  0
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-03  2
2014-01-04  3
2014-01-09  4
```

When I do `a.resample('2D').apply(lambda x: x[0])` I get `IndexError: index out of bounds`. I suspected this was because I was trying to call the 0 element of an empty series, but it seems this is not the case, and rather it's a problem with using `.apply` to the resample. I say this because of this result:

```
a.resample('2D').apply(lambda x: min(x))

            index
0   
2014-01-01  index
2014-01-03  index
2014-01-05  index
2014-01-07  index
2014-01-09  index
```

For the record, `a.resample('2D').apply(lambda x: x.min())` works well. Any idea how to get the first item of every two days and return NaN when there's none?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
a.resample('2D').first()
Out[251]: 
            index
0                
2014-01-01    0.0
2014-01-03    2.0
2014-01-05    NaN
2014-01-07    NaN
2014-01-09    4.0
```

The reason x[0] doesn't work is because there are gaps in the date range which will have 0 rows in that group. You can check it by doing:

```
a.resample('2D').apply(lambda x: len(x))
Out[257]: 
            index
0                
2014-01-01      2
2014-01-03      2
2014-01-05      0
2014-01-07      0
2014-01-09      1
```

A way to fix this is to add a check:

```
a.resample('2D').apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x)>0 else np.nan)
Out[258]: 
            index
0                
2014-01-01    0.0
2014-01-03    2.0
2014-01-05    NaN
2014-01-07    NaN
2014-01-09    4.0
```

Comment: It seems this is the answer. But I'm still curious, why does `.apply(lambda x: x[0])` does not work? What if I wanted to get say, the 20th item in the series or apply some function that can't be written in one line?

Comment: @Ryunaq, I've updated my answer. With a check on the length first,  you can then pick what ever row you like without causing errors.

Comment: Yep, you did it faster than what it took me to type the question lol, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need [`Resampler.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first.html):

```
print (a.resample('2D').first())
            index
0                
2014-01-01    0.0
2014-01-03    2.0
2014-01-05    NaN
2014-01-07    NaN
2014-01-09    4.0
```